# Upsampling images in frequency domain using Pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, fft

I'm trying to upsample an RGB image in the frequency domain, using Pytorch. I'm using [this article](https://www.imageeprocessing.com/2015/11/upsampling-in-frequency-domain.html) for reference on grayscale images. Since Pytorch processes the channels individually, I figure the colorspace is irrelevant here.

The basic steps outlined by this article are:

1. Perform FFT on the image.
2. Pad the FFT with zeros.
3. Perform inverse FFT.

I wrote the following code for the same:

```py
import torch
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = src = cv2.imread('orig.png')
torch_img = torch.from_numpy(img).to(torch.float32).permute(2, 0, 1) / 255.
fft = torch.fft.fft2(torch_img, norm="forward")
fr = fft.real
fi = fft.imag
fr = F.pad(fr, (fft.shape[-1]//2, fft.shape[-1]//2, fft.shape[-2]//2, fft.shape[-2]//2), mode='constant', value=0)
fi = F.pad(fi, (fft.shape[-1]//2, fft.shape[-1]//2, fft.shape[-2]//2, fft.shape[-2]//2), mode='constant', value=0)

fft_hires = torch.complex(fr, fi)
inv = torch.fft.ifft2(fft_hires, norm="forward").real

print(inv.max(), inv.min())
img = (inv.permute(1, 2, 0).detach()).clamp(0, 1)
img = (255 * img).numpy().astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('hires.png', img)
```

The original image:

[image: The original image:]

The upscaled image:

[image: The upscaled image]

Another interesting thing to note is the maximum and minimum values of the image pixels after performing IFFT: they are `2.2729` and `-1.8376` respectively. Ideally, they should be 1.0 and 0.0.

Can someone please explain what's wrong here?

Comment: Side note: I downscaled the final image due to file size restrictions on StackOverflow. The image provided captures the problem well enough though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual convention for the DFT is to treat the first sample as 0Hz component. But you need to have the 0Hz component in the center in order for padding to make sense. Most FFT tools provide a shift function to circularly shift your result so that the 0Hz component is in the center. In pytorch you  need to perform `torch.fft.fftshift` after the FFT and `torch.fft.ifftshift` right before taking the inverse FFT to put the 0Hz component back in the upper left corner.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = src = cv2.imread('orig.png')
torch_img = torch.from_numpy(img).to(torch.float32).permute(2, 0, 1) / 255.
# note the fftshift
fft = torch.fft.fftshift(torch.fft.fft2(torch_img, norm="forward"))

fr = fft.real
fi = fft.imag
fr = F.pad(fr, (fft.shape[-1]//2, fft.shape[-1]//2, fft.shape[-2]//2, fft.shape[-2]//2), mode='constant', value=0)
fi = F.pad(fi, (fft.shape[-1]//2, fft.shape[-1]//2, fft.shape[-2]//2, fft.shape[-2]//2), mode='constant', value=0)

# note the ifftshift
fft_hires = torch.fft.ifftshift(torch.complex(fr, fi))
inv = torch.fft.ifft2(fft_hires, norm="forward").real

print(inv.max(), inv.min())
img = (inv.permute(1, 2, 0).detach()).clamp(0, 1)
img = (255 * img).numpy().astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('hires.png', img)
```

which produces the following `hires.png`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! One clarification - I'm padding the edges of the FFT. So why is the 0Hz component not in the center?

Comment: Each "pixel" in the FFT image corresponds to a weight for a complex sinusoid. The frequency of that sinusoid is proportional to the distance of the pixel from the upper left corner (the 0Hz component). Your goal when upsampling like this is to insert new high frequency components (below the Nyquist rate) with zero weight. By shifting, then padding, then shifting back you are doing exactly this. However, if you don't shift at all then you are effectively zeroing out many of the low frequencies and shifting the old low frequency weights to high frequencies which is why flat regions become black.

Comment: A more direct answer to your question is: the inverse FFT always considers the upper left to be the 0 hz component. If you pad the image with zeros without shifting then the 0 hz component in the upper left will have 0 weight.